Fine-tuned t5 transformer generates repetitive output
I am trying to fine-tune a t5 transformer to generate recipes from a list of ingredients. However, after training, I will ask the model to generate recipes with the following input text: "generate a recipe: whole chicken, rice, eggs" and it will output the following:
Generated output: a recipe: whole chicken, rice, eggs, rice, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, eggs, rice, rice, egg
I am completely new to this so can you provide a comprehensive explanation. The following code is everything I have so far:

preprocess.py
class RecipeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer_name='t5-base', max_token_len=512):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name)
        self.max_token_len = max_token_len

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        row = self.dataframe.iloc[index]
        input_text = row['input_text']
        target_text = row['target_text']

        input_encoding = self.tokenizer(
            input_text,
            max_length=self.max_token_len,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        target_encoding = self.tokenizer(
            target_text,
            max_length=self.max_token_len,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        return {
            'input_ids': input_encoding.input_ids.flatten(),
            'attention_mask': input_encoding.attention_mask.flatten(),
            'labels': target_encoding.input_ids.flatten()
        }


def _load_data(filepath="../data/raw/ds_1.csv", fill_value='missing', columns_to_cast=None, sample_size=None):
    # Load the data
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

    # Sample the data if sample_size is provided
    if sample_size is not None:
        df = df.sample(n=sample_size)

    # Handle missing values
    df.fillna(fill_value, inplace=True)

    # Ensure correct data types
    if columns_to_cast is None:
        # Cast all columns to string if no specific columns are provided
        for column in df.columns:
            df[column] = df[column].astype(str)
    else:
        # Only cast specified columns to string
        for column in columns_to_cast:
            df[column] = df[column].astype(str)

    return df


def find_unwanted_data_types(df, desired_type=str):
    mismatched_data = []
    for col in df.columns:
        for index, value in df[col].items():
            if not isinstance(value, desired_type):
                mismatched_data.append((index, col, type(value).__name__))

    return mismatched_data


def _preprocess_ingredients(df):
    """Converts stringified ingredients list into a Python list."""
    df['Ingredients'] = df['Ingredients'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
    return df


def _preprocess_instructions(df):
    """Cleans up the instructions text."""
    df['Instructions'] = df['Instructions'].str.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
    return df


def preprocess_data(df):
    """Applies all preprocessing functions to the DataFrame."""
    df = _preprocess_ingredients(df)
    df = _preprocess_instructions(df)
    # Add any additional preprocessing steps here
    return df


def _format_for_t5(df):
    df['input_text'] = df['Ingredients'].apply(
        lambda ing: f"Generate recipe instructions for ingredients: {', '.join(ing)}.")
    df['target_text'] = df['Instructions']
    return df


def load_and_prepare_data(filepath="../data/raw/ds_1.csv", test_size=0.1, sample_size=None):
    df = _load_data(filepath, sample_size=sample_size)
    df = preprocess_data(df)
    df = _format_for_t5(df)
    train_df, val_df = train_test_split(df[['input_text', 'target_text']], test_size=test_size)
    return train_df, val_df


def get_data_loaders(train_df, val_df, batch_size=4):
    train_dataset = RecipeDataset(train_df)
    val_dataset = RecipeDataset(val_df)

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

    return train_loader, val_loader


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataframe = _load_data()

    # Check for data types other than str (adjust as needed)
    mismatches = find_unwanted_data_types(dataframe)

    # Print mismatches
    for index, col, dtype in mismatches:
        print(f"Row {index}, Column '{col}' has an unwanted data type: {dtype}")


train.py
train_df, val_df = load_and_prepare_data()
train_loader, val_loader = get_data_loaders(train_df, val_df, batch_size=4)

def setup_model(tokenizer_name='t5-base', learning_rate=5e-5):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name).to(device)
    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    return model, optimizer, device


def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, scheduler, device, num_epochs=3):
    model.train()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        total_loss = 0
        progress_bar = tqdm(train_loader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}")

        for batch in progress_bar:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}

            outputs = model(**batch)
            loss = outputs.loss
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()

            total_loss += loss.item()
            progress_bar.set_postfix({'Training Loss': total_loss / len(train_loader)})

        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} finished. Training loss: {total_loss / len(train_loader)}")


def process_input(input_text, model, tokenizer, device):
    # Tokenize the input text
    inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512).to(device)

    # Generate output
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs.input_ids,
                                 attention_mask=inputs.attention_mask,
                                 max_length=100,  # Adjust max_length as needed
                                 num_beams=4,  # Adjust num_beams as needed
                                 early_stopping=True)

    # Decode the output tokens
    output = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load and prepare the data
    sample_size = 1000  # Define your sample size or set it to None to use the full dataset
    train_df, val_df = load_and_prepare_data(sample_size=sample_size)

    # Proceed as before
    train_dataset = RecipeDataset(train_df)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, num_workers=16)

    model, optimizer, device = setup_model()

    num_train_steps = len(train_loader) * 3
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=num_train_steps)

    # Start training
    train(model, train_loader, optimizer, scheduler, device, num_epochs=3)

    tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-base")
    # Save model and tokenizer
    model_path = r"..\models\t5-base"
    tokenizer_path = r"..\models\t5-base"
    model.save_pretrained(model_path)
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(tokenizer_path)


main.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loaded_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("../models/t5-base/base-v1")
    loaded_tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("../models/t5-base/base-v1")

    input_text = "generate a recipe: whole chicken, rice, eggs"
    input_ids = loaded_tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt")
    output_ids = loaded_model.generate(input_ids, max_length=1000)
    output_text = loaded_tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    print("Generated output:", output_text)


sample data
title
Miso-Butter Roast Chicken With Acorn Squash Panzanella
ingredients
['1 (3½–4-lb.) whole chicken',
'2¾ tsp. kosher salt, divided, plus more',
'2 small acorn squash (about 3 lb. total)',
'2 Tbsp. finely chopped sage',
'1 Tbsp. finely chopped rosemary',
'6 Tbsp. unsalted butter, melted, plus 3 Tbsp. room temperature',
'¼ tsp. ground allspice',
'Pinch of crushed red pepper flakes',
'Freshly ground black pepper',
'⅓ loaf good-quality sturdy white bread, torn into 1" pieces (about 2½ cups)',
'2 medium apples (such as Gala or Pink Lady; about 14 oz. total), cored, cut into 1" pieces',
'2 Tbsp. extra-virgin olive oil',
'½ small red onion, thinly sliced',
'3 Tbsp. apple cider vinegar',
'1 Tbsp. white miso',
'¼ cup all-purpose flour',
'2 Tbsp. unsalted butter, room temperature',
'¼ cup dry white wine',
'2 cups unsalted chicken broth',
'2 tsp. white miso',
'Kosher salt',
'freshly ground pepper'
instructions
"Pat chicken dry with paper towels, season all over with 2 tsp. salt, and tie legs together with kitchen twine. Let sit at room temperature 1 hour.
Meanwhile, halve squash and scoop out seeds. Run a vegetable peeler along ridges of squash halves to remove skin. Cut each half into ½""-thick wedges; arrange on a rimmed baking sheet.
Combine sage, rosemary, and 6 Tbsp. melted butter in a large bowl; pour half of mixture over squash on baking sheet. Sprinkle squash with allspice, red pepper flakes, and ½ tsp. salt and season with black pepper; toss to coat.
Add bread, apples, oil, and ¼ tsp. salt to remaining herb butter in bowl; season with black pepper and toss to combine. Set aside.
Place onion and vinegar in a small bowl; season with salt and toss to coat. Let sit, tossing occasionally, until ready to serve.
Place a rack in middle and lower third of oven; preheat to 425°F. Mix miso and 3 Tbsp. room-temperature butter in a small bowl until smooth. Pat chicken dry with paper towels, then rub or brush all over with miso butter. Place chicken in a large cast-iron skillet and roast on middle rack until an instant-read thermometer inserted into the thickest part of breast registers 155°F, 50–60 minutes. (Temperature will climb to 165°F while chicken rests.) Let chicken rest in skillet at least 5 minutes, then transfer to a plate; reserve skillet.
Meanwhile, roast squash on lower rack until mostly tender, about 25 minutes. Remove from oven and scatter reserved bread mixture over, spreading into as even a layer as you can manage. Return to oven and roast until bread is golden brown and crisp and apples are tender, about 15 minutes. Remove from oven, drain pickled onions, and toss to combine. Transfer to a serving dish.
Using your fingers, mash flour and butter in a small bowl to combine.
Set reserved skillet with chicken drippings over medium heat. You should have about ¼ cup, but a little over or under is all good. (If you have significantly more, drain off and set excess aside.) Add wine and cook, stirring often and scraping up any browned bits with a wooden spoon, until bits are loosened and wine is reduced by about half (you should be able to smell the wine), about 2 minutes. Add butter mixture; cook, stirring often, until a smooth paste forms, about 2 minutes. Add broth and any reserved drippings and cook, stirring constantly, until combined and thickened, 6–8 minutes. Remove from heat and stir in miso. Taste and season with salt and black pepper.
Serve chicken with gravy and squash panzanella alongside."

The class transformers.GenerationConfig has two parameters that you could use to deal with this:
repetition_penalty
This reduces repetition by introducing a penalty for tokens that have already been used.

(float, optional, defaults to 1.0) — The parameter for repetition penalty. 1.0 means no penalty.

You can supply this to the model.generate() method, e.g.:
output_ids = loaded_model.generate(
    input_ids,
    max_length=1000,
    repetition_penalty = 2
)

As you might expect, there is a trade-off between avoiding repetition and hallucination (as the model is forced to choose words with a lower probability). This balance is outlined in this paper, where they say, We find that using a greedy sampling and θ ≈ 1.2 yields a good balance between truthful generation and lack of repetition. You may have to play around with this a little to find the ideal value for your model.
no_repeat_ngram_size
This is outlined in this Hugging Face blog post, The most common n-grams penalty makes sure that no n-gram appears twice by manually setting the probability of next words that could create an already seen n-gram to 0.

(int, optional, defaults to 0) — If set to int > 0, all ngrams of that size can only occur once.

This can also be passed to model.generate():
output_ids = loaded_model.generate(
    input_ids,
    max_length=1000,
    no_repeat_ngram_size = 2
)

As the linked blog post points out, this is effective but you have to be very careful with it. For example, if you set it to 2 in a scrambled eggs recipe, it would only use the phrase "scrambled eggs" once.

this stopped the repetition but it still did not generate anything meaningful

meaning the output is now something along the lines: "whole chicken, rice, and eggs"
